# How to disable Print to File option while printing in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, printers

I am using PRINTDLG library for an old windows application, that has to print some files. I configured it in a way that it pick up the default printer and print the document without showing any dialog box. But the problem is when there is no printer and the default printer is set to save to file it shows a popup to save the file and the application minimises, that should not be happen. SO I want to diable the print to file functionality. I tried to set the flag to disable print to file but it is not working.. Anybody know the solution or a way to disable the system popup.
Here is the sample code:

```
PRINTDLG pd;

memset(&pd, 0, sizeof(pd));

pd.lStructSize = sizeof(pd);
// Disable print to file flag
pd.Flags = PD_RETURNDEFAULT | PD_RETURNIC | PD_DISABLEPRINTTOFILE;
if (!PrintDlg(&pd))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, _T("No printer found"), _T("Printer Error!"), MB_OK);
}
else
{


    DOCINFO di;
    memset(&di, 0, sizeof(di));
    di.cbSize = sizeof(di);
    StartDoc(pd.hDC, &di);
    StartPage(pd.hDC);

    
    // Drawing code begin
    //    
    RECT rc;
    rc.top = 100;
    rc.left = 100;
    rc.bottom = 300;
    rc.right = 300;

    HBRUSH greenBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 0));
    FillRect(pd.hDC, &rc, greenBrush);
    DeleteObject(greenBrush);
    //
    // Drawing code end

    EndPage(pd.hDC);
    EndDoc(pd.hDC);
    DeleteObject(pd.hDC);
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this but does win32 EnumPrinters function tell you if there is no connected printer? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/enumprinters

Answer (score 0):

I sure hope you figured this out by now, just do this to not execute the code:

```
BOOL bRet = m_pAppPtr->GetPrinterDeviceDefaults(&pd);

if (bRet)
{
```